# javascript elasticsearch - works on local instance but not on server?

Tags: javascript, http, elasticsearch, server, cors

I have a javascript visualization script that uses tweets which are indexed in elasticsearch (digested by tweepy library), the tweets are getting through to elasticseach and all is working fine, however the visualization only works with my local instance of elasticsearch (even if i connect to it through server and both instances of elasticsearch are running), if i disconnect the local elasticsearch and try to run the javascript it doesnt work and im getting a `TypeError: response is undefined` and  `Unable to revive connection: http://localhost:9200/`.

What do i need to change so it works from the elasticsearch instance rather than the local instance?

here is the javascript code:

```
    $(function() {
    // Data
    var colors = ["#8dd3c7","#ffffb3","#bebada","#fb8072","#80b1d3","#fdb462","#b3de69","#fccde5","#d9d9d9","#bc80bd","#ccebc5","#ffed6f"];
    var client = new elasticsearch.Client({
        host: 'localhost:9200',
        log: 'trace'
    });
    var index = "tw"; 
    var loadData = function() {

        var data_count = 10000;
        client.search({
            index: index,
            q: "*.*",
            size: data_count,
            sort : 'timestamp:desc'
//                        sort: '_id'

        }, function (error, response) {
            hits = response.hits.hits;
            data = hits.map(function(element, index, array) {
                return element._source
            });
//                        console.log(data);

            formatTWEEPY(updateVis);
//            
        });
    };

    loadData();

    // Instantiate vis
    var timesets = sm.vis.timesets()
        .colors(colors)
        // .setMode("background")
        // .applyLayout(false)
        .verticalMode("ellipse")
        .elementMode("gradient")
        .showSettings(true)
        .margin({ top: 0, right: 180, bottom: 0, left: 25 });

    // Update the vis
    var updateVis = function() {
        // Update dimension
        var width = $("svg").width();
        var height = $("svg").height();
        timesets.width(width).height(height - 30);

        d3.select(".sm-timesets-demo").attr("transform", "translate(0, " + height + ")");

        redraw();
    };


    function redraw() {
        d3.select(".sm-timesets-demo").datum(data).call(timesets);
    }


    function formatTWEEPY(callback) {

        data.forEach(d => {
            d.themes = d.hashtags.map(function(t) {return t.text});
            d.time = new Date(d.timestamp);
            d.title = d.message;
        });

//        console.log(data)
        var hashtags = flatten(data.map(function(t){return t.themes}))
//        console.log(hashtags)
        var dict = hashtags.reduce(function (p, c) {
            p[c] = (p[c] || 0) + 1;
            return p;
        }, {});

        var items = Object.keys(dict).map(function(key) {
            return [key, dict[key]];
        });

        themes = items.sort((a, b) => d3.descending(a[1], b[1])).slice(0, 10).map(e => e[0])


        data = { events: data.slice(), themes: themes };
        callback();
    }
});

function flatten(arr) {
  return arr.reduce(function (flat, toFlatten) {
    return flat.concat(Array.isArray(toFlatten) ? flatten(toFlatten) : toFlatten);
  }, []);
}
```

I have tried to add an IP to the server instead of the `host: 'localhost:9200'` however it made no difference, it still did not work. Ive added these lines to my elasticsearch.yml on both server instance as well as local one so it allows the connection:

```
http.cors.enabled: true
http.cors.allow-origin: "*"
http.cors.allow-methods : OPTIONS, HEAD, GET, POST
```

I have tried this example from elastic website and im getting the elasticsearch cluster is down response but not sure how to fix it so i get the correct respose:

```
    client.ping({
  requestTimeout: 30000,
}, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error('elasticsearch cluster is down!');
  } else {
    console.log('All is well');
  }
});
```

The elasticsearch in running is 6.2

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

please provide `systemctl​ ​status​ ​elasticsearch` output

works for me after editing `/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`

> http.cors.enabled:​ ​ true
>
> http.cors.allow-origin:​ ​ "*"

```
$​ ​apt-get​ ​install​​ elasticsearch-6.2.deb
$​ systemctl​ enable​​ elasticsearch  # important    
$​ systemctl​ ​start​ ​elasticsearch
```

Comment: the response im getting is ```No command 'systemctl​' found, did you mean:
 Command 'systemctl' from package 'systemd' (main)
systemctl​: command not found, but i have systemd installed etc (its ubuntu 16.04) so i guess something wrong with my elasticsearch installation??

Comment: `root@vis4sense:/bin# systemctl status elasticsearch.service
● elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-03-28 10:34:58 UTC; 17min ago
     Docs: http://www.elastic.co
 Main PID: 1240 (java)
    Tasks: 86
   Memory: 1.7G
      CPU: 40.343s
   CGroup: /system.slice/elasticsearch.service
           └─1240 /usr/bin/java -Xms4g -Xmx4g -Xms1g -Xmx1g -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancy`

Comment: systemctl status elastisearch.service is on now,  still getting the elasticsearch cluster is down! response

Comment: yes  i did `systemctl enable elasticsearch.service Synchronizing state of elasticsearch.service with SysV init with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install... Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable elasticsearch` and im still getting same response